# How do I adjust the timing on VS2013's Navigate To preview when just typing digits

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm in the process of migrating to VS2013 and am finding the operation of the Navigate To preview annoying and unusable at times.

We have a large number of files in the solution with names starting with 4 digits, i.e. 0001..., 0065..., 1735..., etc.

When using the preview tab to try to select one on these, it seems that it is either selecting much too quickly or interpreting something incorrectly as when I type the sequence <kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> to look at files in the range 0060... to 0069..., VS2013 invariably opens the 0001... file and the '6' gets inserted as first character.

This seems to happen no matter how fast I try to type the filename, often in well under a second. It also only seems to happen with files having a numeric prefix; if I type <kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, for example, I can pause, review the list and resume typing without a problem.

How do I adjust or reset the preview's autoselect time so I can get a chance to see the list and the preview and select the right file when typing digits as the start of the filename?

So far, the only workaround I've found is to turn off the Preview Tab in the Navigate To options, which is rather disappointing as, when it works, it's extremely useful.

FYI, the VS2013 version is "Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 Version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1".

Comment: No repro at all.  The preview appears quickly but it just gets replaced when I keep typing.  At no point does it enter digits in the preview file.  Something is stealing the focus away, disable add-ins and extensions one-by-one to find the troublemaker.  Note that the file type is relevant, you didn't mention it.  I only checked .cs files.

Comment: Thanks for looking. It's definitely weird behaviour and only affects typing digits. If I type `Ctrl-,` `d<`, for example, the mini progress bar under the textbox stops halfway and I can wait indefinitely. If I type `Ctrl-,` `0` (or any digit), the progress bar goes all the way across, the file gets selected and opened (all without my touching keyboard or mouse). And  if I type `Ctrl-,` `Letter`...wait...`Del` `Digit`, it will open the first file it finds containing that digit immediately! P.S. File type seems to be irrelevant.